# How can I simplify these nth-child selectors? Possible patterns?

Tags: jquery, css, css-selectors

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VK6kE/)

How can I simplify these nthchild selectors:

```
body {
    width:1012px;
}

div {
    width:1em;
    height:1em;
    float:left;
}

div:nth-child(10n+1),
div:nth-child(10n+4),
div:nth-child(10n+5),
div:nth-child(10n+6),
div:nth-child(10n+8) {
    background:#3498db;
    border:1px solid #ecf0f1;
}
div:nth-child(10n+2),
div:nth-child(10n+3),
div:nth-child(10n+7),
div:nth-child(10n+9),
div:nth-child(10n+10) {
    background:#ecf0f1;
    border:1px solid #3498db;
}
```

jQuery

```
for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    $('body').prepend('<div></div>');
}
```

I appened 1000 div elements to the body. How is it possible to shorten the nth-child selectors? Or.. can I use jquery to replace the nthchild selectors? Anything that makes it readable would be very nice.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: can you explain what do you expect from this code and how you understand it?

Comment: thanks for comment. Im wondering if there is a possible pattern to simplify these selectors. they are too long, can they be shortened?

Comment: here is an answer http://jsfiddle.net/VK6kE/1/ the selectors are shorter, but the code longuer!

Comment: @nicolallias How can I fix my post?

Comment: Fix it to describe the problem you're trying to solve by creating these selectors in the first place. Quite likely the solution is not to use nth-child selectors at all. Without understanding the purpose it's hard to give a good answer.

Comment: I don't consider your question to be bad as it is now, the inclusion of code helped a lot. However, you don't seem to be having "a problem" per se, you just want an optimization if possible. Correct me if I'm wrong on that. If you want an optimization, SO is not the best place for it, since we like to solve "errors", not "prettify" code. But! Go to [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/), they like these questions. Copy this question there, as it is, and add *how* you want to simplify them, less words? less jquery processing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always simplify your selectors like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/VK6kE/2/

```
div {
    width:1em;height:1em;
    float:left;
    background:#ecf0f1;
    border:1px solid #3498db;
}
div:nth-child(10n+1), div:nth-child(10n+4), div:nth-child(10n+5), div:nth-child(10n+6), div:nth-child(10n+8) {
    background:#3498db;
    border:1px solid #ecf0f1;
}
body {width:1012px;}
```

What I did was:

- set the white-ish style as the default
- let the others override this style

This way you can eliminate 5 selectors without increasing code.

Also as posted by another user in comments (nicolallias) and as per the OP request, I will also add the way to shorten it with more javascript code:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 1000; i++){
    switch(i%10){
        case 1:
        case 4:
        case 5:
        case 6:
        case 8:
            $('body').prepend('<div class="one"></div>'); break;
        case 2:
        case 3:
        case 7:
        case 9:
        case 0:
            $('body').prepend('<div class="two"></div>'); break;
    }
}

.one {
    background:#3498db;
    border:1px solid #ecf0f1;
}
.two {
    background:#ecf0f1;
    border:1px solid #3498db;
}
```

Comment: thanks that is better. I will have to look at what you did. it might be better in jquery too | dont know why my question gets downvote though.. its not like im clueless. Im not coming back here for answers thats for sure!!

Comment: I think it gets downvoted since there is this new hype with the Code Review branch of StackOverflow and some people consider this to go there. Still, in my opinion this is a programming question and as it is now it is formulated ok.